# How to Install Visual Studio 2017-2019 with puppet/chocolatey

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have use Puppet/Chocolatey to configure visual studio 2010-2015. The last release of VS 2017-2019 has change a bit because of the new online installer method and I am still searching for a solution to install them with Puppet/Chocolatey. When I execute my VS package, only the installer of visual studio will be installed and not the  entire software. Also, if I launch the installer from my client computer I can't do anything, [no one option is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVqzn.png)

Here is a picture of my [ChocolateyInstall.ps1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTTzG.png) File.

EDIT*:

I also have my [Common.ps1 File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6pzt.png).

And finally the [.JSON File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2bvL.png) called "VS2017CustomInstall.JSON".

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the features that you need and put them on a network share.

The official documentation explains this process step by step :
 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-administrator-guide?view=vs-2019

Comment: Like I said I have already successfully configure and install VS2010 to VS2015 without any issue so yes I have already create and configure my network share. If you need more information I have edit my thread with the informations/picture of my Common.ps1 and .JSON Files.